# Could the Avatar theoretically be evil?

Tags: magic, avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

There have been many debates and answers when trying to find out. From this, I have always wondered if, without evil powers, could the Avatar be evil? Not like an anti-avatar, but the main, chosen avatar themselves be personally evil? For this term of "evil", I mean as in they are not anti-heroes or misguided good guys. What I mean is if the avatar becomes greedy and a celebrity, and then forms a god complex and so on. From things like this, or even something like antisocial personality disorder, could the Avatar become evil, like say, where he/she is their world's equivalent to Homelander?

Comment: Given that the Avatar is basically the same person reincarnated endlessly, I fail to see how they could turn out evil

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/screenrant.com/last-airbender-no-evil-avatar-villain-reason/amp/

Comment: [What do you mean by 'evil'](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/144/resolution-of-the-contradictory-definitions-of-lawful-and-chaotic-in-dungeons-an).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wA4QvJISA54

Comment: [Moral relativism](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AboveGoodAndEvil) is usually a pretty good sign that you're dealing with someone that's actually evil.

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no. Since the [Avatar](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Avatar) (capital A) is an avatar of the Spirit of Light, [Raava](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Raava) (combined with the body and spirit of whoever is chosen as the reincarnation of [Wan](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Wan)), it's simply not possible for the Avatar to be evil, any more than light can be dark. I think we can assume that if the host wasn't pure of heart to begin with, they couldn't be the avatar of the Light Spirit. The very idea would be a logical contradiction.

That all being said, not all avatars (small a) are good. We encounter the Dark Avatar (a fusion of the Spirit of Darkness, [Vaatu](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Vaatu) with a human named [Unalaq](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Unalaq)) in the episode *[AtLA: Darkness Falls](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Darkness_Falls)*. They're very **very** naughty indeed, with their stated aim being to usher in "*a thousand years of darkness*"

[image]